# iterate an cJSON nested object in c

Tags: c, cjson

How to iterate nested cJSON object? i want to get(print) all keys and values from deviceData parent object in C. Its a cJson object.

```
 obj =     {      "command": "REPLACE_ROWS",
            "table": "Device.XXX",
            "deviceData": {
                    "device0": {
                      "DeviceName": "Filtered Device",
                        "MACAddress": "112233445599"
                    },
                    "device1": {
                        "DeviceName": "Filtered Device",
                        "MACAddress": "112233445599"
                    },
                    "device2": {
                        "DeviceName": "Filtered Device",
                        "MACAddress": "112233445599"
                    }
           }
    };
```

how to print keys of deviceData (ex device0 device1 device 2 and so on) in C. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What problems do you have with your code? How does, or doesn't it work? Can you please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us? And if you haven't done so yeyt, please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Jochimpileborg :Thanks for your comment.Will post clear questions next time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Supposing `obj` is a string containing your object, you parse it then use `next` to iterate:

```
cJSON * root = cJSON_Parse(obj);
cJSON * deviceData = cJSON_GetObjectItem(root,"deviceData");
if( deviceData ) {
   cJSON *device = deviceData->child;
   while( device ) {
      // get and print key
      device = device->next;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. In while loop i printed key using printf("Key is %s",device->string);

Answer (score 1):

There's a comment in the cJSON documentation about iterating over an object:

> To iterate over an object, you can use the cJSON_ArrayForEach macro the same way as for arrays.

See: https://github.com/DaveGamble/cJSON#objects

The `cJSON_ArrayForEach` macro basically does the same as ilya's proposal, but it avoids relying on cJSON implementation details.

Comment: About the implementation detail: I try to not break API and ABI, this means that this will work for 1.x.x versions indefinitely without `cJSON_ArrayForEach`. The cJSON struct in v2 will change for sure, but `next` and `child` will probably stay the same. (I'm the maintainer of cJSON).